# android, which dependency to use if needs AdvertisingIdClient

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-ads-api

having function to get AdvertisingIdClient.Info

```
private static AdvertisingIdClient.Info getAdsClientInfo(@NonNull final Context context) throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException, IOException, GooglePlayServicesRepairableException {
    int isGPAvailable = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (isGPAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
    }
    return null;
}
```

it uses AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context)

there are three libs in  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

```
Google Mobile Ads   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0
Android Advertising ID (AAID)   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0
Lightweight version of Google Mobile Ads com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:20.1.0
```

what are the difference among these, and which one is safe to use for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0` is fine for this case but change the `GoogleApiAvailability` to `GoogleApiAvailabilityLight` and it will be included in this dependency.